# Undefined local variable or method `unconfirmed_email' when registering users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I just installed Devise in my app, configured the views and everything. However, when I click the sign up button I get this error:

```
NameError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
undefined local variable or method `unconfirmed_email' for #<User:0x00000103721b28>
```

Why is this? Also, I'm using tlsmail to send emails out through my gmail business account. This might be a problem as well.

Comment: This usually indicates a missing column in the database for models like User. You may need to refer to the Devise documentation to see if you need to run a migration to add it.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

unconfirmed_email is required for reconfirmable. For some reason this was enabled by default in config/intializers/devise.rb:

```
config.reconfirmable = true
```

All you have to do is set this to false.

Comment: And restart the server.

Comment: Or add that field to the model: rails g migration AddUnconfirmedEmailToUser unconfirmed_email:string

Answer (score 37):

You miss unconfirmed_email column in db.

add `t.reconfirmable` in migrations and run `rake db:migrate`

or if you're using devise >= 2.0

```
t.string   :unconfirmed_email
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually didn't want reconfirmable, for some reason it was enabled by default. See my answer.

Comment: what is `t.reconfirmable` ? do you possibly mean `t.string  :unconfirmed_email` ? oops, a bit late =)

Comment: @trushkevich, no ! devise has its own helper methods (like reconfirmable), you just need to call devise module name, and it will do all migrations to make it work.

Comment: @Fivell, sorry I did't see dates of question and answer. At that time it was correct (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style)

Answer (score 0):

`config.reconfirmable = true` is in place to ensure that when/if a user wishes to change their email, the also confirm that email just like the initial email the registered with. Only modify this to `config.reconfirmable = false` if you do not want this feature.

In my opinion, building a secure system requires that this feature is in place.

So, you could create a migration to add reconfirmable to your schema as suggested by @fivell

```
rails g migration AddReconfirmableToUsers reconfirmable:string
rake db:migrate
```

You could also just stop your server, drop the db, uncomment t.string :reconfirmable in you devise.rb and create you db again except if you cannot afford to!!.

[image: Line in devise.rb]

```
ctrl + c # kill server
rake db:drop
# uncomment line 28 (as at the time of this post) in devise.rb as in the attached image
rake db:create db:migrate
```